# Could not create connection to MySQL database server using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wrote this program and I just started using JDBC and MySQL:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sql_invoicing?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, "root", "****");
        System.out.println("Connection established......");
    }
}
```

I am getting the below errors when I run it. Can someone help fixing this?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2088)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at Main.main(Main.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "this.serverVariables" is null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1863)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
    ... 14 more
```

I verified that the database was running and the username and password were correct.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using, and which version of MySQL? At a guess, you're using a 5.1.x version of Connector/J and MySQL 8. You need to upgrade to the latest 5.1.x or to the 8.0.x version of MySQL Connector/J if you want to connect to MySQL 8.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try adding this before calling getConnection?
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: Given the stacktrace clearly shows the MySQL Connector/J driver is getting used, this advice makes no sense. Since Java 6 (JDBC 4), drivers are loaded automatically if the driver has the right service definition files (and drivers released in the last decade and a half have those).